# Why does the abs of this positive double equal zero?

Tags: c++, floating-point, c-standard-library

I have a function working on a `vector <vector <double> >`. At some point I want to use the absolute value of an element in a comparison, and I was getting wrong behaviour, so I put in the following debug line:

```
std::cout << M[3][2] << " " << abs(M[3][2]) << "\n";
```

And the output, surprisingly, is:

```
0.667 0
```

Why is this?

Comment: because abs() has an `int` return type? if you want to deal with floats, then there's `fabs()`.

Comment: @MarcB That's available as `abs` in C++ too. [Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs). Just make sure to include `<cmath>`.

Comment: And in C++, all standard library components are in the `std` namespace, even the C functions (which are sometimes also provided in the C forms (e.g., without overloading) in the global namespace, but this is not mandatory, and some platforms don't provide it). So, you should use `std::abs` (or `std::fabs`), or through a `using std::abs;` statement followed by just `abs`. That's the standard-compliant way to use C functions in C++.

Comment: @MikaelPersson That's incorrect. The C++ standard requires `<math.h>` to provide those same overloads in the global namespace. Commonly used implementations fail to conform to the standard, true, but that doesn't change what is and isn't standard.

Comment: @hvd That's a deprecated requirement (see Annex D of C++11 standard). I generally never recommend using any deprecated features, even if it is strictly-speaking still standard-compliant to use them. The general recommendation is to always use `<cname>` instead of `<name.h>`, and when you do so, things are only required to appear in the `std` namespace (although some implementations pull them into global namespace too). As far as I'm concerned, those are the rules to follow. Don't use deprecated features in *new code*, they are there to keep old code from breaking.

Comment: @MikaelPerrson For recommendations that's fine, but for talk of compliance it's important to remember that deprecated features are still part of the language. Support for `<math.h>` is mandatory.

Comment: @MikaelPersson (Apologies for misspelling your name earlier.) BTW, I don't know if it's interesting to you, but it's taken a very long time for the committee to decide what they want it to mean when they deprecate something. It's been decided after years to define a deprecated feature as "having been identified as a candidate for removal from future revisions", but by that definition, there is a chance that if it were brought up, C headers would become undeprecated. They're not recommended, but to the best of my knowledge, there's not even any hint that they're going to go away.

Answer (score 7):

You're probably calling one of the [integral overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) of `abs`, defined in `<stdlib.h>` or `<cstdlib>`, so your argument is being truncated.

You should `#include <cmath>` to pick up the [floating point overloads.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs)

Comment: I did include cmath. Shouldn't it recognise that I'm calling with a double as an argument and choose accordingly.

Comment: @andrepd It should. Try `std::abs`.

Comment: He cannot be using one of the integral overloads of abs, because for that to be true he had to `#include` some prototype for them, as in C++ it is **mandatory** to declare/define a function before use.  On other side, he has used a `double` as argument, so he need at least a function with double argument to match that (or to include a `extern "C"` variant --C++ disables overloading for these).